# The project type is not supported by current installation

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am trying to open a project in Visual Studio. I have [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET) and C# installed. When I open the solution, it says

```
"The project file D:\MyProjects\ComboSample.csproj can not be be opened."
"The project type is not supported by current installation"
```

What do I need to install? C# is already there.

#### ComboSample.csproj

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 10.00
# Visual Studio 2008
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "ComboBoxSample1", "ComboBoxSample1\ComboBoxSample1.csproj", "{6A1F1EE5-4AED-40E0-9517-3EAC47442628}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {6A1F1EE5-4AED-40E0-9517-3EAC47442628}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {6A1F1EE5-4AED-40E0-9517-3EAC47442628}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {6A1F1EE5-4AED-40E0-9517-3EAC47442628}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {6A1F1EE5-4AED-40E0-9517-3EAC47442628}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Comment: Please open the csproj file in a text editor and look for a line that starts with <ProjectTypeGuids>. Post this line here and/or search for the GUIDs that you find there.

Comment: Which version of VS are you using?

Answer (score 3):

That depends entirely on what the project *is* - you can only determine that from the project-type guid. Ultimately it relates to a project type for which you don't have support installed. For example, any of CF / WinRT / MonoDroid / XNA / Reporting / Silverlight / Phone 7 / IDE-extension project etc, if your IDE doesn't have support for those installed. Or anything else!

Maybe a unit-testing project if you are using "express", or a database project if you aren't using db-pro/ultimate. Or a web-application project if you are using VS2005 vanilla.

- find the guid in the csproj
- google the guid and see what it is
- install that tool

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes I get this error when I double click `.sln` files created in previous versions of Visual Studio. Try opening Visual Studio, use `File>Open` and choose the `.sln` file. This should do any conversion, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio 20xx Express for C# you get this error if you try to open a WebProject.

Install Visual Web Developer 2010 Express http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-web-developer-express.

There are a few project types that are simply not supported by the Express editions (e.g. Windows Services) but you can still build a windows service without the template and tooling.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. My issue was that the project need it MVC3. I installed the Web Platform Installer, installed MVC3 and my issue was gone!